# Setting environment variables in WinDbg

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, clr, windbg

I want to introduce new environment variable into a process (in particular, the equivalent of `set COMPLUS_HeapVerify=1` to debug a .Net process). How to do it in WinDbg? Is there a way to do it without restarting a debugging session?

Comment: Do you have to set the environment in *another* process? Can't you just set it in the process from which it is started? (The environment is copied from the parent process upon process creation.)

Comment: Even if there is a way, it is unlikely to help in your particular case as most "configure runtime behavior" settings are read once at startup...

Comment: @Јοеу The parent process in my case is Visual Studio. The point is how to do it from WinDbg. Besides, I'd like to know whether I could introduce a _new_ variable in peb, not just to change existing in memory.

Comment: @user2341923: Visual Studio *also* inherits its parent's environment (usually Explorer). And few applications actually deal with a changing environment during their lifetime because it's always *them* that change *their own* environment. Sure, there is no technical reason why WinDbg shouldn't be able to do this, but I cannot see a useful reason why it *should*.

Comment: @Јοеу Take it as en exercise in using WinDbg. I can change existing environment variable (e.g. find address of `BeingDebugged` via `!peb` and then change value in memory). But what about introducing something new via WinDbg?

Comment: I like the question, even if it is of academic nature. On the other hand side, I'd like to see what you have already tried, e.g. the way you changed existing environment variables. Did you check whether they are read by .NET if you query for an environment variable? Show me an SSCCE for that (fully working sample code + debug commands) and I'll go on from that point, checking what I can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

`environment is part of PEB    Peb->ProcessParamenters->Environment` .

retrieving pointer to environment in debugee cmd.exe

```
hackenv:\>cdb -c "dt ntdll!_PEB -y proc->env @$peb;q" cmd.exe | grep Env
      +0x048 Environment : 0x00010000 Void
```

**find** the **size of the memory block** for the retrieved address

```
hackenv:\>cdb -c "!address 0x10000;q" cmd.exe | grep -i size
Region Size:            00003000
```

find the address of last string in this area

```
hackenv:\>cdb -c "s -[1]su 0x10000 L?3000;q" cmd | tail -n 3
0x00011340
0x000113d4
quit:
```

`write the new Environemt String` **at the end of the last string** `duly null terminating the last string` .

`the end in example below is at` **0x11412** duly null terminating the last environment string

```
hackenv:\>cdb -c "db 1140c l 10 ;q" cmd | grep 1140c
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'db 1140c l 10 ;q'
0001140c  49 00 20 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  I. .............
```

`write your env string at this address`

in the example below a `new enviroment string HACKENVVAR` is set in `cmd.exe` and cmd.exe is executed to print the environement **var using set H command**

```
hackenv:\>cdb -c "ezu 11412 \"HACKENVVAR=1337\";g;q" cmd /c set HACK | grep -i 1
337$
HACKENVVAR=1337
```

Comment: And hope that your buffer overrun didn't clobber something important.

Comment: @ ben yes there exists a remote possibilty for unexpected behaviours when undocumented or unsupported things are done.